# Dynamically add items from input with show vuejs

Tags: vue.js

there was a point where I got stuck while trying to make invoice transactions with vue js, I can add a new item, it works fine, the problem starts here, when I want to show the "description" and "discount_value" that I have hidden, it adds it to all lines, not like this, whichever index button is clicked. add his item. Thank you in advance for your help.

```js
const app = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    data: {
        addAciklama: false,
        addIndirim: false,
        faturasections: [
            {
                name: "",
                unit_price: 0,
                net_total: 0,
                description: '',
                discount_value: '',
            }
        ],
    },
    methods: {
        addNewFaturaSatiri() {
            this.faturasections.push({
                name: "",
                unit_price: 0,
                net_total: 0,
                description: '',
                discount_value: '',
            });
        },
        removeFaturaSatiri(faturasectionIndex) {
            this.faturasections.splice(faturasectionIndex, 1);
        },
    }
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.4.2/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
<section>
    <div class="card-body border-bottom-light" v-for="(fatura, faturasectionIndex) in faturasections" :key="faturasectionIndex">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-4 col-12 mb-1 mb-sm-0 hizmet">
                <div class="form-floating">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" v-model="fatura.name" placeholder=" "/>
                    <label>HİZMET / ÜRÜN</label>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-2 col-12 mb-1 mb-sm-0 brfiyati">
                <div class="form-floating">
                    <input type="number" class="form-control" v-model.number="fatura.unit_price" placeholder=" "/>
                    <label>BR.FİYAT</label>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-1 col-12 mb-1 mb-sm-0 toplam">
                <div class="form-floating">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" v-model="fatura.net_total" placeholder=" "/>
                    <label>TOPLAM</label>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-1 col-12 mb-1 mb-sm-0">
                <div class="mb-1">
                    <div class="mb-1">
                        <button v-if="!addAciklama" @click="addAciklama = !addAciklama" class="dropdown-item">description</button>
                        <button v-if="!addIndirim" @click="addIndirim = !addIndirim" class="dropdown-item">discount_value</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <button class="btn btn-icon btn-secondary" @click="removeFaturaSatiri(faturasectionIndex)">DELETE</button>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="aciklamalar" class="row mt-1">
            <div class="col-12 d-flex">
                <div class="col-sm-6 fatura-aciklama">
                    <div class="row" v-if="addAciklama">
                        <div class="f-a">
                            <div class="input-group">
                                <span class="input-group-text kdv">AÇIKLAMA</span>
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" v-model="fatura.description"/>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="f-b">
                            <button class="btn btn-icon btn-outline-secondary" @click="addAciklama = !addAciklama">DELETE</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-5">
                    <div class="d-flex flex-column">
                        <div class="row row mb-1" v-if="addIndirim">
                            <div class="i-i">
                                <div class="input-group">
                                    <span class="input-group-text kdv">İNDİRİM</span>
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control" v-model="fatura.discount_value"/>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="i-s">
                                <button class="btn btn-icon btn-outline-secondary" @click="addIndirim = !addIndirim">DELETE</button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <hr>
    </div>
    <div class="card-body">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-2">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-secondary btn-sm"
                        data-repeater-create @click="addNewFaturaSatiri()">
                    <span class="align-middle">NEW INVOICE</span>
                </button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

`addAciklama` and `addIndirim` are global variable which is defined in `data` property and it's obvious that if you change them, it applies to every iteration of your `v-for` block and not apply for each index separately.
In order to fix this, you can move `addAciklama` and `addIndirim` into each object in `faturasections`:

```
faturasections: [{
    name: "",
    unit_price: 0,
    net_total: 0,
    description: '',
    discount_value: '',
    addIndirim: false,
    addAciklama: false,
}],
```

Then in your template section code, you should replace all `addIndirim` and `addAciklama` to `fatura.addIndirim` and `fatura.addAciklama`. this will fix your issue.

Comment: Example in codepen: https://codepen.io/nimaebrazeh/pen/JjJNZLd

Comment: So how logical is that?

Comment: Well, you use only two global parameter for knowing which item has description and discout_value. but it's obvious that each item should has it's own "addIndirim" and "addAciklama". because if we only use two parameter, when it's value change applies to all items which is not correct. but if we use "addIndirim" and "addAciklama" for each item in array, if a value for each item change it's not applied to another items.